# Asking for update

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

I want to get an update on COVID-19. So can I post in a group like" As a precautionary measure against COVID-19, the state government has declared one week shut down of offices and colleges. It would be helpful if you guys can share update on this issue. Thank you."  Is it polite to use guys in this sentence?

Comment: Questions asking us to check and improve the phrasing are considered "proofreading" and are not on topic.  If you can identify a specific concern then this may be on topic.  For example. What do you think is impolite about this.  Why do you have a doubt?  You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @Priyadarshini Thirunavukkarasu Hi! I noticed your added question about using "you guys". I have edited my answer to include an answer about that specifically. I hope it helps!

Comment: This question is about the politeness of "you guys". COVID-19 is incidental to the question and distracting. It would be better if it was replaced with a nontopical topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As a precautionary measure against COVID-19, the state government has declared one week shut down of offices and colleges. It would be helpful if you guys can share update on this issue. Thank you.

Overall, this message you want to send is very clear and polite.

I would note two small things. The first is that we would add an indefinite article between "declared" and "one". So that would read "...has declared a one-week shut down..." The reason is that the indefinite article "a" is actually attached to the noun "shut down". In this case, "one-week" is an adjective that describes "a shut down".

The second thing is that "you guys" is a fairly casual phrase. I note this because, based on the content of your message, it is targeted to a work or professional environment.

**Edit Addition:** Using "you guys" is not rude, generally. There are exceptions - for example, if we refer to a group of people that is only women as "you guys," depending on the age of those women, those women might find "you guys" rude. A general trend is that women who are more than 40+ year-old are *more likely* to find "you guys" as rude. People who are less than 40+ use "you guys" casually to refer to people of any gender. Returning to your original question, in context, "you guys" is not rude, but it is also not the most polite phrase we could use.

So several, more formal alternates could be:

"the staff"
"the administrators"
"everyone"
"employees"

so rephrased, it might be:

"It would be helpful if **the staff shares** this update on the issue."
"It would be helpful if **the administrators share** this update on the issue."
"It would be helpful if **everyone shares** this update on the issue."
"It would be helpful if **employees share** this update on the issue."

Good luck, and stay safe!